# PHP Odd time when adding

Tags: php, math, time

To get time I do this

```
$day_timmer = time()
echo $day_timmer;

This is what printsout 1332533147
```

But when I add to it I get this

```
$day_timmer = time() * 1000; 
echo $day_timmer;
This is what printsout 1.332533387E+12
```

No clue what I'm doing wrong.

So I get voted down for wondering why letters are in my numbers lol

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: The number which is produced by multiplying those numbers is very big so it is displayed in E notation - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation

Comment: @j08691 Gee thanks, I think I have a valid question. When you expect numbers to be returned and you end up with a E+12

Comment: You may have a valid question, however you need to take a moment and explain it rather than just dropping some code and adding "No clue what I'm doing wrong.". If you expect us to spend some time trying to help you, the least you can do is put some effort into your question.

Comment: Didn't want to bloat the question, just wanted to know why there was letters in what I would expect to just be numbers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's called scientific notation, and it's all right. `E+12` stands for 10<sup>12</sup> and in your case, this is exactly the given number:

```
1.332533387E+12 = 1.332533387 * 10^12 = 1,332,533,387,000
```

Comment: ...which would normally overflow a 32-bit signed integer, so PHP uses a floating-point number instead

Answer (score 1):

To fix your problem use the following statement.

```
<?php 
echo date("h:i a"); 
?>
```